# Get subscriber model based on e-mail address

Tags: magento-1.9

I'm trying to read newsletter subscriber in Magento 1.9 from app\code\community\Salesmanago\Sso\Model\Observer.php with below code:

```
$subscriberRaw = Mage::getModel('Mage_Newsletter_Model_Subscriber')
                        ->getCollection()
                        ->addFilter('email',$subscriber['email']);
```

It gives me error:

```
There has been an error processing your request
Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.

Error log record number: 1500596311195
```

How to enable printing the errors? What's the proper way to get value from model with where clause.
Where can I find good guide for learning Magento?
Thank you! :)

Comment: rename the file local.sample.xml to local.xml under error and then you will see the exact error and also update your question with full error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To enable errors display on magento , open index.php :

```
//Comment if condition here
  //if (isset($_SERVER['MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE'])) {
    Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
 //}

 //set display_errors to 1
 ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

The proper way to get a newsletter subscriber by email :

```
 Mage::getModel('newsletter/subscriber')->loadByEmail($subscriber['email'])
```

A good guide to learn Magento here (I don't know a lot of guides ) :

https://alanstorm.com/category/magento/